# deshabilitar opcion en lista desplegable

Tags: mysql, foreach

Tengo un error en el código que estoy realizando, ya que me está duplicando las opciones de una lista(agenda) que va por lapsos de 15 minutos.

El formulario me graba todo muy bien y cuando vengo con el foreach a deshabilitar de la lista despegable la hora que ya ha sido tomada previamente para no duplicar citas me la deshabilita muy bien, el problema es que si hay por ejemplo 20 citados, la lista me la repite 20 veces...cómo hago para que no me esté repitiendo la lista y sólo me muestre deshabilitado la hora previamente escogida?

Aqui una imagen:

[image: lista desplegable]

Aquí el código actual:

```
            <select name="escogerHora">
            <?php
                $id = '1';
                $fechaEscogida = '2018-08-28';
                $desde = '14:30:00';
                $hasta = '19:00:00';
                $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT TIME(fecha) AS fecha
                FROM AGENDA WHERE id = '".$id."' AND DATE(fecha) = '".$fechaEscogida."'
                AND TIME(fecha) BETWEEN '".$desde."' AND '".$hasta."'
                ");
                $sth->execute();
                $results = $sth->fetchAll();
                foreach($results as $row) :
            ?>
                <option value="14:30" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '14:30:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>2:30 P.M.</option>
                <option value="14:45" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '14:45:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>2:45 P.M.</option>
                <option value="15:00" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '15:00:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>3:00 P.M.</option>
                <option value="15:15" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '15:15:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>3:15 P.M.</option>
                <option value="15:30" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '15:30:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>3:30 P.M.</option>
                <option value="15:45" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '15:45:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>3:45 P.M.</option>
                <option value="16:00" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '16:00:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>4:00 P.M.</option>
                <option value="16:15" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '16:15:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>4:15 P.M.</option>
                <option value="16:30" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '16:30:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>4:30 P.M.</option>
                <option value="16:45" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '16:45:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>4:45 P.M.</option>
                <option value="17:00" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '17:00:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>5:00 P.M.</option>
                <option value="17:15" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '17:15:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>5:15 P.M.</option>
                <option value="17:30" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '17:30:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>5:30 P.M.</option>
                <option value="17:45" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '17:45:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>5:45 P.M.</option>
                <option value="18:00" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '18:00:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>6:00 P.M.</option>
                <option value="18:15" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '18:15:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>6:15 P.M.</option>
                <option value="18:30" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '18:30:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>6:30 P.M.</option>
                <option value="18:45" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '18:45:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>6:45 P.M.</option>
                <option value="19:00" <?php if ($row["fecha"] == '19:00:00') {echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?>>7:00 P.M.</option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Tu problema es netamente lógico, no de programación; en la consulta que realizas en la BD estas obteniendo todas los agendamientos de un día especifico y en el foreach estas recorriendo cada uno de esos agendamientos y poblando el select con las horas... por ende si existen por ejemplo 5 agendamientos en un día la lista la repite 5 días...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lógicamente te repite las horas tantas veces como citas hayas registrado. Una solución rápida y sencilla podría ser que montases un array no asociativa con las fechas que te devuelve la consulta, eliminar el bucle y usar la función [in_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para comparar las horas citadas con la hora del desplegable.

```
$id = '1';
$fechaEscogida = '2018-08-28';
$desde = '14:30:00';
$hasta = '19:00:00';
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT TIME(fecha) AS fecha FROM AGENDA WHERE id = 
'".$id."' AND DATE(fecha) = '".$fechaEscogida."' AND TIME(fecha) BETWEEN 
".$desde."' AND '".$hasta."'");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
$horas = array();
foreach($results as $key => $value){
    $horas[] = $value['fecha'];
}

<select name="escogerHora">
    <option value="14:30" <?=(in_array('14:30:00', $horas)?'disabled':'')?>>2:30 P.M.</option>
</select>
```

Te he puesto el ejemplo con una hora, con las demás, el mismo proceso. Hay mejores formas de hacerlo pero aquí tienes una respuesta sin muchos cambios en tu código.
Saludos!

Comment: Muy Buenas unzip0, Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Te recomiendo leer el  [como elaborar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para la próxima :)

Comment: Buenas Txema, gracias por iluminarme el camino.